# Methods describe the temporal consistency of kernel density data

Tags: time-series, clustering, kernel-smoothing, consistency, gis

I am working on a spatial time series analysis project. The task is to study the spatial distribution of point features (e.g., crime events, traffic accidents) over time. I aim to find the places with the following characteristics given the spatial distribution of point features across time:

- places with consistently high-level concentration of point features
- places with periodically high-level concentration of point features. "periodic" here might mean that this place only has a great number of point features during special events (e.g., ceremony and the national day)
- places with suddenly high-level concentration of point features

I have used the [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) method to compute the density of places across the study area through the study timeline. This way, I can get the time series of kernel densities for each location on the map, i.e., a matrix in which rows represent locations and columns denote the time. Then what's next? How can I statistically find places with a large number of point features but different temporal consistency levels over time? For instance, the following figure shows the spatial distribution of kernel densities of locations in New York City for four continuous periods (in total I have about 15 periods). The red color means the high kernel densities while the green color represents the low kernel densities.

[image: Spatial Distribution of Kernel Densities Across the New York City in Four Continuous Periods]

I have tried to use the clustering techniques (e.g., KMeans and KShape) offered by [tslearn](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package in Python to cluster time series of kernel density values of all the locations. But I can only differentiate them somehow visually. Are their any statistical methods to achieve this goal?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the evolution of Moran's I over time? One might also want to compare periods $i$ and $i+1$ using the Mantel test but I have not used it personally.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you for your comment! Computing Moran's I over time is a great idea. But this metric can only offer me a general perception of spatial autocorrelation over time, i.e., test whether the places with high KDE tend to be spatially adjacent to each other in the city scale over time. But it might not help in finding the specific locations in the city with consistently high-density point features...